# Nodejs AWS Lambda Functions dependencies not installing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I've created a lambda function which was developed in SAM. Now when I've pushed all the code to the lambda function however when I trigger it it seems like it doesn't install the necessary dependencies like mysql etc

Shouldn't it automatically npm install all the required libraries? Or do I need to manually push the node_modules dir to the lambda function as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the node_modules bundleded with your lambda function.

Lambda executes the code straight away without an install step.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html